# C++ Reading data from a file (containing spaces) line by line

Tags: c++, file, whitespace

I'm programming a game on a board 9x9 (which is a char 9x9 array). I wrote a method that saves the current game state in a file going according to the scheme bellow:

```
board.plansza[0][0]
board.plansza[0][1]
board.plansza[0][2]
board.plansza[0][3]
(...)
*points in int*
```

(Where every line is just a one character/space/number)

Now I need a method that's gonna read this file and put the data back in the same kind of array (if someone decided to stop playing, saved the game and then wanted to continue from previous state) as well as the variable for points.
The problem is that some of the lines in a saved file are just a space (' ') and all the methods I've tried are failing to read it properly because of that.

The latest way I tried (and failed):

```
for (int i = 0; i < ROZMIAR; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < ROZMIAR; j++){
            zapis << board.plansza[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }

zapis << user.pkt << endl;
```

**How do I read a file line by line if some lines contain only a space (which I don't want to ignore)?**

Comment: [`while(std::getline(fileStream, lineString) { // do a thing }`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Also, please don't post screenshots of code, include the code in the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/), like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");
  std::string line;
  char matrix[10][2];
  int i = 0;
  while(std::getline(infile, line))
  {
      std:cout << line << std::endl;
      if(line .find_first_not_of(' ') != std::string::npos)
      {
          // There's a non-space.
          matrix[i++][0] = line[0];
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: '\n' might not be enough to trigger the output, try std::endl. It prints a new line and does a flush.

Comment: Right @Davidbrcz, answer updated, thank you for the upvote!

Comment: @gsamaras printing out yes, but I want to put the data in the proper places in my program (one board and one additional variable) and don't really know how to do it.

Comment: @Ania then you need to update your question with the data structure you want to use (your matrix, for example is it like `int arr[4][5]`?) and a sample small text file.

Comment: @gsamaras I updated it, I hope I contained all you needed.

Comment: @Ania well I updated my answer. Hope that helps. I suggest you to accept my answer and think about the problem again, and then if needed post a new question.

Comment: @gsamaras Thanks for all the help but it doesn't work. It also makes my program just end for some reason (there's a method afterwards that should make you go back to the game whether the reading was successful or not). I think the easiest way is just to fill the array with something else other than spaces, some char. It won't look as good, but I don't think my teacher will mind that much.